# Custom ListView Displaying Last value

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, custom-lists

I have a custom listView with 200 values coming from Cloud DB. All the values are received properly and added in ArrayList(hotelList). When I am passing to  the ArrayList(hotelList) to Custom Adapter class, showing all the values as last element. Many stackOverflow questions found here related to this I tried them too. None worked for me. How should I fix this?
The code is,

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            Log.d("Inside Post", "message");
            root = new JSONObject(result);
            validation = root.getInt("response");
            message = root.getString("message");
            JSONArray data=root.getJSONArray("data");
            data.length();
            if(validation==1) {
                hgs=new HotelGetSetter();//Getting and setting class
                for(int i=0;i<data.length();i++){
                    hgs.setName(data.getJSONObject(i).getString("hotel_name"));
                    hgs.setPlace(data.getJSONObject(i).getString("city"));
                    hotelList.add(hgs);//While Debugging, all the 200 values from db received and added in the ArrayList(hotelList) values also there correctly
                }
                //But after the loop all the values here changed to last element value(debugged).
               mainMethod();
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
 public void mainMethod(){
    HotelCustomAdapter hca=new HotelCustomAdapter(HotelMaster.this,hotelList);
    list_hotel.setAdapter(hca);
    //list_hotel.setAdapter(new HotelCustomAdapter(this, hotel_id1,hotel_name1,hotel_place1));
}
```

Comment: I'm honestly not understanding your question, but looking at your code it looks strange to me that you are building your adapter in post execute. You should build outside and in post execute just invoke adapter.notifyDataSetChanged for having new items on bottom of the list.

Comment: @thetonrifles, Please check the question once. I added comments in the code. After the for loop the (ArrayList<HotelGetSetter> hotelList) has the last value for data.length() times.

Comment: you initialize variable hgs=new HotelGetSetter(); out of for loop and then you are always editing the same instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you initialize variable hgs=new HotelGetSetter(); out of for loop and then you are always editing the same instance

Comment: Thank you thetonrifles, hypd09

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the values for the same object `hsg` through the loop instead of creating different objects for each set of values. Therefore the 200 same objects.

Just move the `hgs=new HotelGetSetter();` into the loop and it should work.